# How to store values to external file

Tags: javascript, php

I finished a quizgame tutorial in JavaScript but I would like to enchance it now by adding
a highscore to it.

The highscore will contain usernames and their score.
I do not wish to save the data to a database but instead an external file. The reason is because I want to be able to play even if you are offline.

Here is the code that appears when you have finished the quiz and it calculates your score:

```
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function thequestion(){
    pingvin = _("pingvin");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        pingvin.innerHTML = "<h2>You achieved "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("pingvin_status").innerHTML = "Your Quest Has Come To An End";

        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
```

I guess that when you have finished the quest an input field and a submitt button should appear. When clicked the values of the score and the input field get stored inside a txt-file. This is what I need help with and I would appreciate if anyone could take some time and help me out.

Comment: If your entire quiz game is built on JavaScript and you want to save a file on server, then all you can do is to call a php script using `ajax`. But if you want to save a file on the client side then I'm afraid you are not able to (JS security restrictions)

Comment: I think you should use localStorage for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). You can't save a file directly, with Javascript, with a few exceptions, like [Chrome's Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage).

Here are the basics of reading and writing data with localStorage. You want to make an array of scores, convert the array into [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/), and then when you're reading data, you parse the JSON that you saved, and somehow display the scores you saved.

```
if(localStorage){ // make sure the browser supports localStorage

    // WRITING DATA
    // sample array of scores
    var scores = [{"Player 1" : 1000}, {"Player 2":900}, {"Player 3": 800}]; 
    // save the data under the key "scores"
    localStorage.setItem("scores", JSON.stringify(scores)); 

    // READING DATA
    // if localStorage contains something under the key "scores"
    if(localStorage.getItem("scores") != null)
    {
        // read the data saved in localStorage
        var data = localStorage.getItem("scores"); 
        // turn the data from JSON into an array.
        var scores = JSON.parse(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it with PhP without malfunction too much?

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with PHP. You just need the fopen and fwrite functions, which you can read about here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

But if you want the game to be save high scroes while offline, it's pointless to use PHP, as you will only be able to connect to your local server.

Comment: ItsGreg, surely all the code necessary to store the data will be done in the browser, so PHP will not be involved.

Comment: So do I proceed with PHP or HTML in this situation?

Comment: @Mello, if the quiz is running only in your browser, then it would make more sense to store the data in your browser with Javascript. However, if you want the scores to be public and shared between players, then you'll have to use PHP, but note, that you won't be able to save the score if you're offline, and using PHP.

Comment: @ItsGreg Could you please help me with that code? Iam still a newbie when it comes to PHP.

Comment: @Mello, I've edited the answer to show you an example of reading and writing to localStorage.